# Reusable form fields in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

If i have the following dialog/modal:

```
<Modal
                open={this.state.createAccountModalOpen}
                trigger={<Link size="m" theme="bare" href="#" className="main-menu-item" onClick={this.handleOpenModalCreateAccount}>Create account</Link>}
                closeIcon
                onClose={() => { this.setState({
                    createAccountModalOpen: false,
                }); }}
            >
                <Header icon='add user' content='Create account' />
                <Modal.Content>
                    <Form />
                </Modal.Content>
                <Modal.Actions>
                    <Button color='green' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Icon name='add user' /> Create account
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Actions>
            </Modal>
```

Basically this is a React Semantic-ui Modal/Dialog. Now What i want to do is make Form reusable (the Form component contains 4 input fields), so i can use it in other modals or components. What would be the best way so that when I click on Create account, it gathers the data from the form and then submits it?

Do I have to pass functions to the Form to try store the data in the main Modal component? or is there a better way to get the validated data from the form?

Answer (score 1):

I’m on my phone so I’m limited.

You want to define your custom function in the parent component where you call your Modal. Then pass that function to it as a prop modal onComplete={this.submitEmail}

Then in your modal component call this.props.onComplete in your handleSubmit.

Then from here out you can define the custom function you want to use wiTh the model and pass it through with onComplete={whateverFunction}

In order to only show the inputs that you want you could set up a series of render if statements. Then when you call your Modal you can pass through renderIfText={“email”}  and in your model if this.props.renderIfText=email render email input.

```
import React from 'react';


class ReusableModalForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    };
  }



  handleChange(e) {
   let {name, value} = e.target;
   this.setState({
     [name]: value,
     usernameError: name === 'username' && !value ? 'username must have a value' : null,
     emailError: name === 'email' && !value ? 'email must have a value' : null,
     passwordError: name === 'password' && !value ? 'password must have a value' : null,
   });


 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.onComplete(this.state)
 }

  render() {

    return (
     <Modal
       open={this.state.createAccountModalOpen}
       trigger={<Link size="m" theme="bare" href="#" className="main-menu-item" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>{this.props.buttonText}</Link>}
       closeIcon
       onClose={() => { this.setState({
           createAccountModalOpen: false,
       }); }}
   >
       <Header icon='add user' content='Create account' />
       <Modal.Content>
           <Form />
       </Modal.Content>
       <Modal.Actions>
           <Button color='green' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
               <Icon name='add user' /> {this.props.buttonText}
           </Button>
       </Modal.Actions>
   </Modal>
    );
  }
}



export default ReusableModalForm;
```

Comment: Except my Button is outside the form, so how does it know to handleSubmit?

Comment: inside your modal component handleSubmit(e){ this.props.onComplete() }

Comment: inside your modal component handleSubmit(e){ this.props.onComplete() }.      Here’s an example from my work. https://github.com/arn1313/kritter-frontend/blob/master/src/component/auth-form/index.js       .... in your case authForm would just be form and you would need to add renderIfs based on which inputs you want.

Comment: So put your modal in a component, then render that component wheee you need a modal form

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your `<Form />` reusable you need to determine what are the inputs/outputs to your Form and allow any potential parent component to access/manipulate it via props.

Perhaps something like:

```
<CreateAccountForm 
  input1DefaultValue={...} 
  input2DefaultValue={...}
  onSubmit={yourCreateAccountFormHandler}
/>
```

> Do I have to pass functions to the Form to try store the data in the main Modal component? or is there a better way to get the validated data from the form?

It depends on how you implement Form and your input fields.

I would recommend [react-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form) library or, if you want to have your own implementation - using redux state and wire your inputs/form to redux.
If no redux then you will need to store the state of inputs in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you compose components,  you share data between them using props. I will be passing "name and label" props to stateless functional component named;

input.js

```
import React from "react";
const Input = ({name,label}) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        autoFocus
        name={name}
        id={name}
        className="form-control"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      />
  );
};
export default Input;
```

form.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Input from "./common/input";
class RegisterForm extends Form {
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input name="username" label="username" />
            <input name="email" label="email" />
            <input name="password" label="password" /> 
        </form>
      </div> ); } }
```